# Error al pasar Variables de un Array hacia un Fragment

Tags: android-studio, arraylist

**Buen día estimados, tengo este problema, estoy desarrollando una aplicacion de un carrito de compras, tengo un Array que recibe 3 variables y dichas variables al parecer estan pasando null al fragmento del Carrito de compras lo esta recibiendo como vacío.
este es el Error que me sale**

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.wisdroid.rasel_ii.ui.carrito.CarritoFragment.onCreateView(CarritoFragment.java:40)

```
public class PeluqueriaDAO {

  String nombre_servicio;
  int imagen_servicio;
  double precio_servicio;
  boolean isSelected = false;
  int cantidad;

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public int getCantidad() {
        return cantidad;
    }

    public void setCantidad(int cantidad) {
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

    public PeluqueriaDAO(String nombre_servicio, int imagen_servicio, double precio_servicio) {
        this.nombre_servicio = nombre_servicio;
        this.imagen_servicio = imagen_servicio;
        this.precio_servicio = precio_servicio;
    }


    public String getNombre_servicio() {
        return nombre_servicio;
    }

    public void setNombre_servicio(String nombre_servicio) {
        this.nombre_servicio = nombre_servicio;
    }

    public int getImagen_servicio() {
        return imagen_servicio;
    }

    public void setImagen_servicio(int imagen_servicio) {
        this.imagen_servicio = imagen_servicio;
    }

    public double getPrecio_servicio() {
        return precio_servicio;
    }

    public void setPrecio_servicio(double precio_servicio) {
        this.precio_servicio = precio_servicio;
    }
```

*****Este es mi Adaptador******`

```
public class AdaptadorPeluqueria extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorPeluqueria.ViewHolderPeluqueria> {

    List<PeluqueriaDAO> lista_servicios;
    List<PeluqueriaDAO> carroCompra;
    TextView tvCantProductos;
    Button btnVerCarro;
    int cant_total =0;
    Context context;

    public AdaptadorPeluqueria(List<PeluqueriaDAO> lista_servicios,TextView tvCantProductos,List<PeluqueriaDAO> carroCompra, Button btnVerCarro) {
        this.lista_servicios = lista_servicios;
        this.tvCantProductos = tvCantProductos;
        this.carroCompra = carroCompra;
        this.btnVerCarro= btnVerCarro;
    }

    public AdaptadorPeluqueria(List<PeluqueriaDAO> lista_servicios) {
        this.lista_servicios = lista_servicios;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolderPeluqueria onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate
                (R.layout.item_servicios_peluqueria,null,false);
        return (new ViewHolderPeluqueria(view));
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolderPeluqueria holder, final int position) {

        final PeluqueriaDAO model = lista_servicios.get(position);
        holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(model.isSelected() ? Color.parseColor("#008577") : Color.WHITE);
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(!model.isSelected()){
                        cant_total = cant_total +1;
                        System.out.println("*****************************************");
                        System.out.println(model.getNombre_servicio());
                        System.out.println(model.getImagen_servicio());
                        System.out.println(model.getPrecio_servicio());
                        carroCompra.add(new PeluqueriaDAO(model.getNombre_servicio(),
                                                          model.getImagen_servicio(),
                                                          model.getPrecio_servicio()));
                       Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Se Añadio al Carrito",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else{
                        cant_total = cant_total -1;
                    }
                    model.setSelected(!model.isSelected());
                    holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(model.isSelected() ? Color.parseColor("#008577") : Color.WHITE);
                    model.setCantidad(cant_total);
                    tvCantProductos.setText(""+model.getCantidad());

            }
        });


        holder.nombre_servicio.setText(lista_servicios.get(position).getNombre_servicio());
        holder.precio_servicio.setText(""+lista_servicios.get(position).getPrecio_servicio());
        holder.imagen_servicio.setImageResource(lista_servicios.get(position).getImagen_servicio());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
       if(lista_servicios == null){
           return 0;
       }else{
           return lista_servicios.size();
       }
    }

    public class ViewHolderPeluqueria extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public View v;
        TextView nombre_servicio;
        TextView precio_servicio;
        ImageView imagen_servicio;
        CardView cardView;


        public ViewHolderPeluqueria(@NonNull View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CardViewID);
           nombre_servicio = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombreID);
           precio_servicio = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.precioID);
           imagen_servicio = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagenID);

        }

    }
}
```

Fragmento donde lleno el RecyclerView

```
public class PeluqueriaFragment extends Fragment {


    RecyclerView recyclerViewPeluqueria;
    public ArrayList<PeluqueriaDAO> lista_servicios;
    public ArrayList<PeluqueriaDAO> carro_compra = new ArrayList<>();
    Button verCarrito;
    TextView cantidadServicios;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        lista_servicios = new ArrayList<>();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_peluqueria, container, false);
        recyclerViewPeluqueria = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerPeluqueriaID);
        recyclerViewPeluqueria.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2));
        llenar_servicios();

        cantidadServicios = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCantProductos);
        AdaptadorPeluqueria adapter = new AdaptadorPeluqueria(lista_servicios,cantidadServicios,carro_compra,verCarrito);
        recyclerViewPeluqueria.setAdapter(adapter);


        verCarrito = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ver_carrito);
        verCarrito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    CarritoFragment carritoFragment = new CarritoFragment();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putSerializable("carrito",carro_compra);
                    carritoFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,carritoFragment);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void llenar_servicios() {
        lista_servicios.add(new PeluqueriaDAO("Lavar Cepillar",R.drawable.lavar_cepillar,7.50));
        lista_servicios.add(new PeluqueriaDAO("Lavar Cortar",R.drawable.lavar_cortar,8.50));
        lista_servicios.add(new PeluqueriaDAO("Corte Cabello",R.drawable.corte_cabello,7.90));
        lista_servicios.add(new PeluqueriaDAO("Planchar",R.drawable.planchar,6.90));
        lista_servicios.add(new PeluqueriaDAO("Tinte",R.drawable.tinte,33.90));
        lista_servicios.add(new PeluqueriaDAO("Mechas",R.drawable.mechas,45.90));
    }


}
```

Al parecer aquí me esta causando el Error en esta Linea de código:  carroCompras = (ArrayList) getArguments().getSerializable("carrito");

Aqui dejo el error

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.wisdroid.rasel_ii.ui.carrito.CarritoFragment.onCreateView(CarritoFragment.java:40)

```
public class CarritoFragment extends Fragment {

    public ArrayList<PeluqueriaDAO> carroCompras = new ArrayList<>();
    AdaptadorCarrito adaptador;
    RecyclerView rvListaCarro;
    TextView tvTotal;
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_carrito, container, false);
        carroCompras = (ArrayList<PeluqueriaDAO>) getArguments().getSerializable("carrito");


        PeluqueriaDAO p = carroCompras.get(0);
        System.out.println("*************************");
        System.out.println(p.getNombre_servicio());
        System.out.println(p.getPrecio_servicio());
        System.out.println(p.getImagen_servicio());

         rvListaCarro = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvListaCarro);
         rvListaCarro.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
         tvTotal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTotal);
         adaptador = new AdaptadorCarrito(carroCompras,tvTotal);
         rvListaCarro.setAdapter(adaptador);
        return view;


    }
```

Por favor, ayudenme a solucionar este problema. De antemano les quedo muy agradecido

Comment: Has ejecutado el código en modo debug?

Comment: Si compa, he hecho de todo, he implementado algunas soluciones que he visto en este mismo portal, pero aun asi me sigue saliendo ese error :(

Comment: getArguments() te esta devolviendo null, esto pasa cuando no le pasas los argumentos al fragment. ¿Podrias agregar el codigo donde creas el fragment para ver como le estas pasando los argumentos?.

Comment: Estimado Erick Silva.
En la 3ra secion "public class PeluqueriaFragment extends Fragment "
 muestro como creo el Fragment mediante un Button, ahi creo la instancia  Fragment

Comment: @TonyOrmaza no lo habia visto. El problema es que el Array es serealizable pero PeluqueriaDAO no lo es, entonces no agrega nada con el putSerializable

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que deseas es enviar un `ArrayList` de objetos `PeluqueriaDAO`:

```
public ArrayList<PeluqueriaDAO> carro_compra = new ArrayList<>();
```

debes asegurar que el objeto `PeluqueriaDAO` implementa `Serializable`:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class PeluqueriaDAO implements Serializable{
```

al recibirlo lo debes realizar de esta forma:

```
carroCompras = (ArrayList<PeluqueriaDAO>) getIntent().getSerializable("carrito");
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Si tengo implementada esa clase, pero sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: @TonyOrmaza al recibirlo usa getIntent() en lugar de getArguments().

Comment: @TonyOrmaza si esta respuesta soluciono el problema recuerda marcarla como solución , revisa [tour], saludos.